# unable to use pecl_http-2.5.1

Tags: software-installation, 15.04, php

I installed pecl_http-2.5.1 but i cant seem to be able to use it:

```
http\Client\Request' not found.
```

phpinfo() has no indication of http being enabled.

what have i done wrong?

Comment: What's your Ubuntu version? You have tagged three releases.

Comment: oh right sorry, 15.04 and php5.6.4

Comment: any suggestions would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea, how you have installed `pecl_http-2.5.1` but to use `pecl-http` you need `php5-pecl-http`. Therefore

```
sudo apt-get install php5-pecl-http
```

Be in mind, that the package is provided by the [Universe repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=pecl&searchon=names).

Comment: that has been installed also